# Nginx location prefix for rewrite

Tags: nginx

I'm little bit stuck. I have this Nginx location block

```
location /sandbox {
    rewrite /test /script.php last;
}
```

And for URL `/sandbox/test` it works as intended. However, It would also capture this URL `/sandbox2/test` and that is not what I want. I want this block to capture ONLY `/sandbox/test`.

As far as I understand Nginx matches the remainder of the URL inside the block. So, I though this

```
location /sandbox {
    rewrite ^/test$ /script.php last;
}
```

would solve the problem. But when using this block Nginx gives me `404 Not Found nginx`.

I need to keep the `/sandbox` as the prefix for multiple rewrites inside, so something like below works but it is not a solution for me.

```
rewrite ^sandbox/test$ /script.php last;
```

Any hints what I might be doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your assumption that "Nginx matches the remainder of the URL inside the block" is wrong. Using `location /sandbox/` will remove the `/sandbox2/test` case.

Comment: Using `location /sandbox/` just moves the problem elsewhere. When `location /sandbox/` is used it will capture urls like `/sandbox/2test` which is also not a solution to 'capture ONLY /sandbox/test'. Altho if the assumption that "Nginx matches the remainder of the URL inside the block" is wrong could you point me to the right direction?

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to achieve, and why you cannot use `rewrite ^/sandbox/test$ ...`

Comment: Short anwser: legacy reasons. Long asnwer: I want to have a file which is contatining many many rewrites likes `rewrite ^/test$ /script.php last;`. I want to be able share this one file among many instances with prefix such as `location /server_one { include rewrite file }`, `location /server_two { include rewrite file }`. If the rewrites are not stricly capturing only the URL they are intended to. It will create many unwated URLs.